# Install EJabberd on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xmpp, ejabberd, azure-web-roles

Is it possible to install **EJabberd** XMPP Server on my Azure Cloud App? I want to do this for the testing purpose. If it is possible, then how do I open ports which are required to communicate with the Jabber Server.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean Azure Cloud App as "Windows Azure Cloud Service" you will not be able to run it due to several application specific limitation.

However if you decide to use Windows Azure Virtual Machines either [Linux](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/) or [Windows](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/) as it does support both Linux and Windows OS, you sure can get it running. You can configure virtual machines ports as needed for your EJabberd server to support TCP/IP based communication to external users. Here are [directions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/) for setting endpoint in Windows Azure  Virtual Machine.

Comment: Can you guide me more? I have create Virtual Machine in Azure. Now I have to install Ejabberd Server on the azure virtual machine? Is this possible? and How can I do that?